# If a rotating ball gets disintegrated to dust or energy what happens to its angular momentum?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotation

Say a rotating ball or neutron star gets completely annhilated to energy by meeting its anti-matter counterpart (also rotating in the same direction), what happens to the angular momentum? It cannot disappear due to conservation laws.

Comment: It could be conserved by the radiation byproducts

Comment: Energy is a property of physical systems, it's not "a thing" like matter, which means that annihilation can set an amount of energy free (which would be in the form of photons and usually other particles) that may be proportional to its rest mass, but it won't be converted "to energy". The resulting radiation from the blast will therefor carry the angular momentum with it. In general, the total energy of the system before and after the reaction is the same, so one can't even say that energy has been "created". Be careful with your "accounting".

Comment: @CuriousOne I could reword it to say "converted to energy" if that makes it correct. What is the mechanism through which electromagnetic radiation carries angular momentum?

Comment: Even if you reword it, it's technically not correct. Matter is physical objects, energy is a property of physical objects (an observer dependent property, too) and it stays the same. There is this misconception out that that matter can be converted into energy, but that's not so. Rest mass, energy and momentum are linked by relativity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be easy to see that if it "disintegrates" into **dust particles**, it is no different than if you have a rotating object, held by a string, and the string is cut.  We know that the angular velocity (momentum) $\omega$ will be converted into a tangential velocity $v$ and the particles will have a momentum $mv$, **in addition** to the momentum generated by the radial energy of disintegration.

For the case were it is all converted to energy, the photons (radiation) will have the equivalent energy of the tangential and radial energy components due to the angular velocity and radial disintegration.
In both cases, the conservation of energy and momentum, will be conserved.